# How can I change the titles and how they show up in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, title, advanced-custom-fields

I never used WordPress but I need to find a way to change titles and how they show up at my job (I'm only an intern in software development).

Ok, so I checked the WordPress wp-admin page, saw the possible posts.
People can post on different topics for the current day, than at the end of the day, they click on a "build report" that simply combine the posts of the day.

The problems:

1. The title in the ACF is not the one that is shown when the post is written. I wonder if they changed it and it's showing the last one, or if it's showing something else, but it's not showing the right thing. I need to be able to change the titles, and without going into the code if possible, so people will be able to change it by themselves later on (on the worst case scenario, I'll do a "how to" for them to change it in the code if there is no other way).
2. In the "day report", the titles are not showing up at all. I need them to be shown on the top of each sections of the day report or the report is really hard to understand.

Ok, so I checked everywhere and I'm still not sure how WordPress works. People seem to either change it from the wp-admin page, or from the php code. I checked on the servers and couldn't find the WordPress code at all (I have another website hosted there and the code is easy to find). I found the WordPress config.php file, nothing more.

In the wp-admin page, I could see and change the titles, but since it's not always those titles that show up, I don't see the point of this page at all. And I don't exactly see how to show the titles in the day report.

Help would be really appreciated guys. It's not really my job to check WordPress, I'm only trying to help them, but I can't seem to get it. I'm a "newbie" in terms of websites, I'm a java/c++ programmer mainly. I started learning JavaScript, PHP and MySQL but I'm far from good with it.

Anyway, thanks a lot for the help guys, I hope I can get to learn WordPress.

PS: I'm sorry for the quality of my English, my main language is French.

Comment: page title as in <title> or post tile as in "Big news click here"?

Answer (score 0):

title can be changed with theme file named **functions.php**

you have to add something like this in you theme's **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'baw_hack_wp_title_for_home' );
function baw_hack_wp_title_for_home( $title )
{
  if( empty( $title ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
    return __( 'Home', 'theme_domain' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'description' );
  }
  return $title;
}
```

look at [wordpress official doc at codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) to learn more about how wordpress works